# Pressing Enter on a <input> submits the wrong <form> (2 forms on 1 page)

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms, input

I have got two different forms on the same page.

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="ajax_send('<?print $userid;?>',this.msg.value); return false;">
<input id="msg" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="msg" stlye="width: 80px;" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Chat here" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

and

```
<form action="?page=about&id=0#comments" method="post">
<textarea class="editbox" id="exitbox" placeholder="Write a comment ..." name="newcomment"></textarea>
<input type="submit" id="submit1" name="submit1"></div></div>
```

Now when I enter something in `<input id="msg"..>` and press enter, it submits the second form instead of the first one.

What am I missing?

Comment: I found out myself. I forgot `</form>` on the second form. I'm stupid (and tired). Sorry

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022697/enter-key-with-multiple-forms-on-a-website

Comment: If Google brought you here, this answer has more solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313032

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your second form isn't closed.

Answer (score 2):

Your second form should by like that

```
<form action="?page=about&id=0#comments" method="post">
<textarea class="editbox" id="exitbox" placeholder="Write a comment ..." name="newcomment"></textarea>
<input type="submit" id="submit1" name="submit1"></div></div>
</form>
```

Comment: BTW your answer fixed my similar problem, so I added this solution to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313032